# XML document opened in Word does not show XML but Word-produced pdf from document does

Tags: microsoft-word, xml

Customer currently opens XML files in word but they display as blank pages. If you save as a PDF from Word the PDF displays correctly.

Have checked all settings, cannot see anything wrong.
Allowed XML 2003 files to open/save
Removed 2016 and installed 365

Ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Since Word 2007, Word files have been XML files (i.e. the docx dotx format). I assume you are referring to trying to use Word as an XML editor. It is poorly suited to this task.

Comment: Also, it depends on how well-formed an XML document is, and whether the built-in XML parser can cope with it. Have customer try XML from another source.